# How do I bulk insert from an excel file that does not have the same columns as the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have an excel file with data for these columns: ID, Name, Phone Number. But the table in SQL also takes the address - which isn't in the excel file. This is causing the following error:

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for column address

If I remove the address column from the table in SQL Server, I do not get this error upon import. I am ok with the address field being blank after import.

Here is my SQL for import:

```
BULK INSERT tableName FROM filePath
WITH (
Datafiletype = 'char',
Fieldterminator = '\t',
Rowterminator = '\n',
Firstrow = 2
)
```

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: This is a hacky way but what stops you from using excel text combination to make a giant INSERT query out of that?

Comment: Like assume you put down `INSERT INTO myTable (Id, Name, Phone) VALUES` and then for each row in the excel sheet you do `="(" + A1 + ",'" + B1 + "','" + C1 + '),"` and just concat that together and then execute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a view:

```
create view v_tableName as
    select id, name, phone_number
    from tableName;
```

Then load the file into the view:

```
BULK INSERT v_tableName FROM filePath
    WITH (Datafiletype = 'char',
          Fieldterminator = '\t',
          Rowterminator = '\n',
          Firstrow = 2
         );
```